# ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 - Read ClaimTypes from metadata URL

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Good Day,

We are trying to get ClaimTypes from metadata URL. We are using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore Version 4.7.1

Here the metadata
[image]

This is the method we are using to get metadata information.
`entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(MetaDataUrl))`

Here the return values
[image]

Is there any way to get ClaimTypes from IDPSSODescriptor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata you are trying to read is WS-Federation and not SAML 2.0. The ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 component only support reading SAML 2.0 metadata.